# R Help! chisquare test

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared, statistical-test

I have a dataset that looks like this

[image]

I'm running a chi-square test to see if...

1. there is a significant difference in frequency of all colors observed between before and after.
2. there is a significant difference in frequency on yellow of before and blue of after
3. If frequency of yellow, blue and orange of before is significantly lower or higher than after.

How should I do this in R? Do I just add all the colors to make a master column?

This is what I have so far

```
colors$combined <-  colors$yellow + colors$blue + colors$red + colors$orange + colors$purple


x1 <- chisq.test(colors$combined,colors$before/after)
x1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat=data.frame(red=c(1,2,0,1,2,0),
               yellow=c(2,1,2,2,1,2),
               blue=c(1,2,2,1,1,2),
               orange=c(2,2,0,0,1,1),
               purple=c(2,2,1,1,1,1),
               when=c(rep("before", 4), "after", "after"))
library(dplyr)
tab=dat %>%
  group_by(when) %>%
  summarize(across(red:purple, mean)) %>%
  select(-when)
chisq.test(as.matrix(tab))
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  as.matrix(tab)
X-squared = 0.075374, df = 4, p-value = 0.9993
```

No, no significant difference across the colors of before versus after.

```
t.test(c(2,1,2,2), c(1,2))
```

No significant difference between yellow of before or blue of after.

```
t.test(c(2,1,2,2), c(1,2))
```

No significant difference between yellow of before and after.

```
t.test(c(1,2,2,1), c(1,2))
```

No significant difference between blue of before and after.

```
t.test(c(2,2,0,0), c(1,1))
```

No significant difference between orange of before and after.

Comment: Thank you, you're right! I should do a t.test not chi square.